# How to model interdependency between fields of a case class?

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

I would like to model some *interdependency* between fields of a case class such that the possible values of the `rhs` field would depend on the type of `lhs`.

In the example below, I had not managed to write `type B = A.B` - it would not compile, only `type B = A#B`. Not surprisingly, in the example below this line does compile: `SomeDomain.Foo(SomeDomain.Brr, SomeDomain.Bee.Pooh)` though this defeats the purpose.

Evidently I am doing something wrong. Is there a small fix here? Or, should I take a different approach altogether?

```
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Domain {
  trait Bar {
    type B
  }
  type A <: Bar
  type B = A#B

  case class Foo(lhs: A, rhs: B)
}

object SomeDomain extends Domain {
  sealed trait Baz extends Bar {
    sealed trait Inner

    override type B = Inner
  }

  case object Brr extends Baz {

    case object Strawberry extends Inner
    case object Raspberry extends Inner
  }

  case object Bee extends Baz {

    case object Honey extends Inner
    case object Pooh extends Inner
  }

  override type A = Baz
}


val foo = SomeDomain.Foo(SomeDomain.Brr, SomeDomain.Bee.Pooh)
val f1= foo.lhs
val f2 = foo.rhs

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Domain
defined object SomeDomain
foo: SomeDomain.Foo = Foo(Brr,Pooh)
f1: SomeDomain.A = Brr
f2: SomeDomain.B = Pooh
```

Comment: You say the purpose is defeated, but I find your purpose unclear... How do you intend to use this?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet, the purpose, and sorry if I was not clear, is to have Foo model a domain where possible values for `B` are influenced by the value in `A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable approach is to use a type member with an explicit type parameter:

```
trait T { type O }

case class Foo[A](t: T { type O = A }, a: A)
```

Comment: thanks! will try it out. Just to make sure, this is not a [Structural Type](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#structural-type) and does not incur its reflection oriented runtime penalty, _right?_

Comment: This uses a type member, which from a runtime perspective is equivalent to a type parameter.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. I wonder though why I had not managed via path dependent types. Just the same I will accept your answer